# What happens if I buy a Joja membership?

Tags: stardew-valley

The mayor said that he'd sell the old community centre if another person bought a Joja membership. They're selling them in the store and I'm tempted to buy one.

What happens if I do buy one? Does the community centre really get sold and, if it does, what happens to everything inside?

Comment: If it were any other game, I'd say the mayor would find a way to *not* sell the community center. In Stardew Valley, I have a feeling something nasty might happen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Buying a Membership at JojaMart from Morris causes the Community center to be destroyed and replaced with a [Joja Warehouse](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Joja_Warehouse). After that, you can buy [bundles](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Bundles) from Joja mart via [Joja Community Development Form](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Joja_Community_Development_Form).

If you are very rich (for example, using Cheat Engine for gold), this is the fastest way to unlock everything. However, don't do that, enjoy the game, enjoy the community center, enjoy doing quest to unlock thing. Just remember how our "main" get away from Joja for a peaceful life, a gift from her/his grandfather.

Comment: It's the renegade path!

Comment: Also, you go to hell because you sold your soul to JojaMart.